# How to change keybindings in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I know there is the keybinding file `/usr/share/inkscape/keys/default.xml`, and I can change it to modify the keybindings. But since it will probably get overwritten on an update, I want to know where else I can put it.

I tried to copy the file to `~/.inkscape/keys/default.xml`, but Inkscape ignored my changes.

Does anyone know where to put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `~/.config/inkscape/keys/default.xml` instead of `~/.inkscape/keys/default.xml`